# License plate recogntion using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, g++, ubuntu-12.04, ocr, tesseract

I got a good Automatic Number Plate Recognition Project from github (https://github.com/kornelik/anpr ). In order to run this we need OpenCV  and Tesseract Optical Character Recognition library (https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/). It works fine in my Ubuntu 12.04 , 32bit system.

The problem is that while I setting the same working code in another system (Ubuntu 12.04 , 32 bit) after configuring OpenCV and Tesseract it produces the following error while making the project.I am struggling to find out what is the issue

The error is

```
g++ -Wall -Werror -O2 -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -Wall -Werror -O2 -c recognizer.cpp -o recognizer.o
g++ -Wall -Werror -O2 -c conio.cpp -o conio.o
g++ -Wall -Werror -O2 -c ocr_char.cpp -o ocr_char.o
ocr_char.cpp: In constructor ‘anpr::OCRChar::Impl::Impl(const     string&, const string&)’:
ocr_char.cpp:17:9: error: ‘set’ is not a member of ‘std’
ocr_char.cpp:17:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’
ocr_char.cpp:17:18: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘char’
ocr_char.cpp:23:17: error: ‘goodChars’ was not declared in this     scope
make: *** [ocr_char.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Maybe some code'll be helpfull? Because it seems to be a syntax error. For example missing semi-coloumn..

Comment: No .. I am check again and again .. It works fine in another system

Answer (score 0):

Is your code updated? On nov 2013 there was a commit to include the set header:
https://github.com/kornelik/anpr/commit/2a63fb362e6fc79ac73f172195a893b37287d3bf

The error message you got seems to be related to that.

Compiled ok on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits.